# Stationarity of $\nabla x_{t}$

Tags: time-series, stationarity

How should I prove that for a given series $x_{t}=\frac{3}{2}x_{t-1}-\frac{1}{2}x_{t-2}+w_{t}$ that is non-stationary, $y_{t}=\nabla x_{t}$ is stationary?

I attempted to get an equation based on the lag operator $B$, defined as $\nabla x_{t} = (1-B)x_{t}$ but I can't obtain roots greater than 1 (which is the condition for stationarity). However, since I have only seen examples dealing with $x_{t}$ instead of $\nabla x_{t}$, it's very likely I'm missing something.

What is the correct procedure in this case?

**UPDATE**:

whuber helped me a lot with this question. Now I have another question as I posted in a comment below:

Is there a general procedure when it is not possible to express $x_{t}$ in terms of $y_{t−i}$'s for some $i$?

Comment: It is rather striking that $y_t = x_t - x_{t-1}$ = $1/2(x_{t-1}-x_{t-2})+w_t$ = $(1/2)y_{t-1} + w_t$.  Does that help?

Comment: Of course it helps :-) Now let me ask another question: Is there a general procedure when it is not possible to express $x_{t}$ in terms of $y_{t-i}$'s for some $i$?

Comment: @whuber You may want to add your comment as an answer :-)